# C# HTML String Display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making an application in MVC3, i am storing a string in database in this format

```
 <a href='path'>Text</a> Happy
```

The field is saving properly but i have to display it in web page with hyper link like

[Text](http://abc.com) Happy

but currently it is showing like

```
 <a href='path'>Text</a> Happy
```

How can i render this string as HTML on web page?

Comment: Maybe these aren't user-generated html fragments in your case, but make sure you understand the risks of script injection when you're doing this.

Comment: So you are making a mistake in "get text from db" method (MrObvious). Can you paste your code to here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're using the Razor template engine:

```
@Html.Raw(mystring)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Razor you can use `@Html.Raw()` as per Phil Haack's [quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

its better you Encode HTML before storing it to database.. If you're using .Net Framework 4 try this

```
String TestString = "This is a <Test String>.";
String EncodedString = Server.HtmlEncode(TestString);
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

Otherwise use [anti xss library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Its workes like a magic and really easy to implement.. Un-Encoded is not only dangerous as it can cause XSS attacks but it also causes problems with rendering on html fornt page.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I would really advice against doing that because it's very hard to guard against script injection problems.

That being said though, if you think that can be managed, you should be able to use @Html.Raw to render the text without escaping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using razor,

and `string text = "<a href='path'>Text</a> Happy";`

Then you want `<%= text %>`,  not `<%: text %>`

As others have said, this is not considered great practice due to HTML injection, but it seems HTML injection is your intention.